# eCharts Tooltip with Pointer

Tags: javascript, php, charts, echarts

I need to get the eCharts tooltip on the line with the pointer like this:
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRdRA.png)

but so far my tooltip is "floating" in the chart with no pointer:
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBmgI.png)

this is my config in a PHP page:

```
'tooltip' => [
    'trigger' => 'axis',
    'axisPointer' => [ 'type' => 'cross' ],
    'axis' => 'x',
    'backgroundColor' => 'rgba(250,250,250,1)',
    'borderColor' => '#5d00f3',
    'confine' => TRUE,
     
    'textStyle' => [
        'fontWeight' => 'bold',
        'fontSize'=> '17',
        'color' => '#000', 
    ],
],
```

**how can i create a pointer to follow the line**, the doc is not very clear to me:
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid.tooltip.position

Comment: Hi @mawnir-fas have you been able to find a solution to this? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @Nipuna No I didn't.